# TypeError: tsDiagnostic.file.getText is not a function

Tags: android, ionic3

When I run `ionic cordova build android` it works right.

But run `ionic cordova build android --prod`
it appears these errors below in the picture

[image]

my ionic info:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
Node              : v8.9.0
npm               : 5.5.1
```

Comment: i create component  html is cause the error why```<div *ngIf="text">
  {{text}}
</div>```

Answer (score 0):

in your module add

```
   import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ]
  })
```

it builds success~

Comment: u can also use 
./node_modules/.bin/ngc find what cause the error